# Turning a div into a link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a div that I create through javascript. In that div I create a link. This is how I create the div and link:

```
    $('#info').find('#link').text("View");
    //Creates a new link
    var eventLink1 = document.createElement('a');
    //Sets link attribute
    eventLink1.setAttribute('href', 'Default.aspx?Title=' + responseArray[3].toString() );
    //Adds link to div
    $('#link').empty();
    $('#info').find('#link').append(eventLink1);
```

When I test the program I find that I can see the link inside the div (through the debugger), but I cannot click on it (It looks as if it is set to `display: none` but there is no css to back that.

How would I edit the code so that the link is click-able?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is likely because your `a` tag has no inner text.  Try this:

```
var eventLink1 = $('<a>Your link text</a>').attr('href', 'Default.aspx?Title=' + responseArray[3].toString())
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to do:

```
eventLink1.appendChild(document.createTextNode('YOUR LINK TEXT HERE'));
```

The reason why you can't see your link is because there is no text there to see!

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't look like the link has a text component.

```
<a href="#">Text here is missing</a>
```

Since you are using jQuery, I suggest you do this sort of thing instead:

```
var eventLink1 = $('<a></a>')
    .attr('href', 'Default.aspx?Title=' + responseArray[3].toString())
    .text('something here (yours is missing)');
$('#link').empty().append(eventLink1);
```

Answer (score 1):

The `<a>` is by default an inline element which completely collapses when it doesn't have a body. So either give it a body, e.g. some text where you can click on, or set its style to `display:block;` so that it expands to the parent's size.

As a completely different alternative, you could also just give the `<div>` an `onclick` function which sets the `window.location` to the new URL (along with a style of `cursor:pointer;`).

Answer (score 0):

To create the element, you just need this:

```
$('#link').append('<a href="Default.aspx?Title=' + responseArray[3].toString() +'">Link</a>');
```

Note: There's no such thing as `display: hidden`. Also, you do not need to use `.find('#link')` as the id attribute should be unique on the page. You just need `$('#link')`

Answer (score 0):

the link doesn't have a text (innerHtml).
Here's how you could do it:

```
$('#link').empty().append($('<a/>',{'href','Default.aspx?Title=' + responseArray[3].toString()}).html('this is the link') );
```